# Make rows in a matrix "interact" with each other

Tags: matlab, loops, for-loop, matrix, sum

Lets say I have a `n x m` matrix, and a function `f` which does something between two rows. How can I make a loop so that all rows have operated on each other with that function `f`.

Example:
Let `f` be the function which sums up the row. Let's say we have a `4x4` matrix. 
So I want to sum up `row 1` with `row 2`, `row 2` with `row 3`, `row 1` with `row 4`, etc. Until all rows have interacted with each other.

- By summing up a row with another row, I mean take the sum of the first row and sum it with the sum of the other row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Version with a loop, assuming `f` is a function that accepts the two rows of `M` as two arguments:

```
count = 0;
result = zeros((n-1)*n/2,1);
for r1 = 1:n-1
    for r2 = r1+1:n
        count = count + 1;
        result(count) = f(M(r1,:),M(r2,:));
    end
end
```

Version without a loop:

```
N = nchoosek(1:n,2);
result = arrayfun(@(r1,r2) f(M(r1,:),M(r2,:)), N(:,1), N(:,2));
```

Comment: THANK YOU FLORIAN !